# can't connect to tfs using VPN

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, vpn

I am trying to connect to TFS using VPN:

At our Offices we have TFS installed and working fine.

we have a team abroad trying to connect to tfs through VPN

our TFS server name at the offices is ***tfssrv*** under with and IP 192.---.---.196, when i ping this IP from abroad, there is connection to it, but when i try to access it from the browser i should get a popup to enter the username and password, which i not getting. also when i try to connect to it from VS and try to add this IP as as the TFS server, i get an error TF31002: unable to connect to team foundation server.

am i missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

Did you have any setting of the firewall on TFS AppTier, such as only allow Domain Inbound?

Can you access other applications via the VPN? 
Can you try to use userid and password to connect to the TFS and see if it works?

Could you please follow the steps in this blog http://blogs.msdn.com/b/granth/archive/2008/06/26/troubleshooting-connections-to-tfs.aspx

Hope it helps!

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue that I resolved.

What I did was the following steps:

- Network sharing allowed for public/domain network
- VPN adopter IPv4 setting, add secondary Domain controller in my network DNS
- In DNS tab, add DNS suffix for this connection ...in your network, both tick mark needed